# Is it important to use labels in java?

Tags: java, label

How important is it to use labels in Java? I haven't seen labels used, except in academic books.

I saw them used with jump statements such as break and continue.

Comment: It may be useful when you want to break a nested loop.

Comment: In over 30 years of development (and the last 16+ in Java), I've never found a need to use labels. Basically, it's better to simply ignore them and pretend that they don't exists - but thats just my opinion

Comment: I agree with @MadProgrammer, whenever I was tempted to use them I realized that my code was actually a mess and restructuring would be the better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use labels, but they are considered bad form in general, sort of unrestrained jumping within a method, it makes the code harder to maintain and can introduce bugs if not handled carefully.

As a rule with OO there is usually an easier/better way to achieve things.

In too many years of coding Java I have never used a label.